# Programmatically add character to TextInput when Hiragana IME is active

Tags: apache-flex, localization, flex4, ime

I'd like to be able to add a character to a TextInput programmatically (say when you press a button) even when using IMEs (I'm using a Japanese IME right now). Normally this would be super easy, i.e.

```
protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
      ti.text = "k";
}
```

where ti is a TextInput component. However, things get a little tricky when using an IME. The code above, for instance, adds a k in ti even if you're using the Hiragana IME.
I looked at the IME documentation and tried something like this

```
protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
      IME.setCompositionString("k");
}
```

at first I thought this was doing the trick, but it seems like it always defaults to what looks like Half-Width Katakana (although I'm not 100% sure), even if the Hiragana conversionMode is currently selected, or if I set it right before setting the composition string. Unfortunately the IME library doesn't seem to be open source so I have no idea if this is a bug or not.

Was wondering if anyone had any advice - I realize this is super specific so the odds are low, but thought I'd try.

thank you!

---

post-edit: here is some code to try out what I'm talking about. Note: you'll need Japanese IME setup on your machine. I'm using this on a Windows 7 box with Japanese IME setup, and running it on standalone Flash. It's hard to see the difference between typing a k in Hiragana and in Katakana, but if you look closely you should notice a difference (and if you type an 'a' right after you should see different results popping up).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- dpcontrols/adg/SimpleADG.mxml -->
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                ti.setFocus();
                try
                {
                    IME.enabled = true;
                    IME.conversionMode = IMEConversionMode.JAPANESE_HIRAGANA;
                    IME.setCompositionString("k");
                }
                catch (error:Error)
                {
                    trace("Unable to set conversion mode.\n" + error.message);
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:VGroup>
        <s:TextInput id="ti"/>
        <s:Button label="go" click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filed a bug - we'll see what Adobe says.

Answer (score 2):

First, look at this link: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=18_Client_System_Environment_6.html

Make sure you have IME enabled and the proper settings.  Second, what version of flex are you using?  Do you have a font that's loaded into the application that can handle the language?

Comment: J_A_X, thanks for the reply. IME is enabled and the conversionMode is properly set when I poll it, but setCompositionString still defaults to a different conversionMode. And yes, all fonts are available - I can type both Hiragana and Katakana in my TextInput just fine. Will add some code to my original posting, in case anyone wants to try to reproduce this.

Comment: sure. Code is in the original post, SWF is here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8639981/bugTest.swf

Comment: test procedure: switch IME on, set conversion mode to Hiragana, type 'k' in textInput; delete 'k', press button, a 'k' appears, but different from the former one.

Comment: Alright, tried it myself, couldn't get it to work either.  I'm not an expert in internalization in Japanese, but it seems to be is that there's a different between the Adobe IME and the Windows IME.  When you're typing, that's the windows IME kicking in, if you use the converter, that's the Adobe one.  You should check bugs.adobe.com/flex/ and if nothing's there, post an issue.

Comment: Awesome - just posted a bug. Thank you for your help!

Comment: BTW, can you think of any clever ways to get around this assuming it's a bug? I was thinking that maybe sending an keydown event to the TI to simulate the user typing something may do the trick but was surprised to find out that TI actually only spit out keydown events but don't listen for them. Also, it seems like when IME is on, the keyup event is the one with meaningful info. Seems like an over constrained problem - and yet it seems like it really shouldn't be.